# Laravel 5.2 ErrorException in FormBuilder.php

Tags: php, css, laravel-5

Laravel 5.2 ErrorException in FormBuilder.php line 1235 Method style does not exist.

I am not sure about this error.
I have already updated my composer.json file with "laravelcollective/html": "^5.2" under "require" section and config/app.php file with

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
```

under aliases section and below code under providers section

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

my layout file contains the following code:
`{!! Html::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') !!}`
As soon as I put this line, the system through the error.
The same code is working fine in my other laravel project

Comment: And what is the error ?

Comment: Hi @MayankPandeyz here is the error: Laravel 5.2 ErrorException in FormBuilder.php line 1235 Method style does not exist. Method style does not exist. (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\lv_project\resources\views\layouts\layout.blade.php) (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\lv_project\resources\views\layouts\layout.blade.php)

Comment: After adding `html` repository have you update the composer?

Comment: Yes.. and my other codes are working, related to form : eg. "{!! Form::open(array('route' => "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
```

You registered `FormFacade` as `Html`.

Try with:

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

should work ;)